# Why am I getting error: "Value Error" - invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'matthew'

Tags: python, django, literals, radix

I am using django/python.

Here's where the data comes from:
User selects one or more options from a `<select name="op_assignedTo">`

I also use `<option value="username">`

The data is sent via POST and collected in a django view:

`op_assignedTo                = request.POST.getlist('op_assignedTo')`

But the following line is give me the error:
`assignedTo_list              = Item.objects.filter(assignedTo__in=op_assignedTo)`

I got the above line from numerous other answers to other questions on stackoverflow.
I am confused at the error, because even the line

`temp = Item.objects.filter(assignedTo='matthew')`

gives the same error, `"Value Error" - invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'matthew'.`

If the first part of my post doesn't quite make sense, please just look at the last line of code I posted.
Thanks all!

Comment: If my guess is incorrect, please post your class def.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query a field across a ForeignKey, use double underscore syntax `__`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

```
temp = Item.objects.filter(assignedTo__username='matthew')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Yuji.

After reading your comment, I tried
`temp = Item.objects.filter(assignedTo__username__in=op_assignedTo)`

where op_assignedTo is a list of 1 or more string values from a `<select>` tag. I still get the ValueType error with this code.

Comment: @user1360155, can you post the error? Try this in the python shell until you find the query that works. If `assignedTo` is an FK field, and the target model has a field called `username` which is a `CharField`, this query will work. Perhaps you haven't restarted your server or the error is unrelated?

Comment: Actually Yuji, I just now got the code to work. I used your correction of the `__` syntax, along with Colleen's explanation of what my code was trying to compare, to realize that I needed to do `Item.objects.filter(assignedTo__user__username__in=op_assignedTo)`

This is because I had a ForeignKey and a OnetoOne link to go across.

So thank you, Colleen, Li-Aung Yip, and Yuji Tomita. You were all very helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

What kind of field is assignedTo? I'd guess it's a foreign key, in which case it's trying to do the filter on an id, when you're passing a string. Am I right?

The problem here is that assignedTo is being treated as an int (either it is an int, or is being compared on the basis of an int, such as a foreign key id), and you're passing a string to compare it to, which is invalid.

Comment: +1 - Which is to say that `assignedTo` is supposed to be a *numeric* identifier of some kind. The literal meaning of the error is "Python can't convert `matthew` to a number in base 10." (Sidenote: in base 36 - `int('matthew',36) = 48543957608L`)

Comment: Thanks for making that clearer, @Li-aungYip! I'll edit my answer to include that clarification.

Comment: Wow, fast responses! Thanks everyone.

Colleen:
assignedTo is a foreign key, and yes you are right.
The foreign model contains:
def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

Does this mean I am comparing a string to a unicode?

Comment: Glad you got it working, and for future reference: the __unicode__ method isn't for comparing, it's for printing, so if you said print modelInstance, you would print whatever is in your __unicode__ method. Hope that makes more sense!